# How to set image to full screen in body Custom CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[image: sample]

Currently the image is added as a Raw HTML with code `<img src="[2019-12-05-07-52-16]___851_Visual-1.jpg" alt="bckgound" class="bg" />` Im guessing its because of the template, how can i override the template and use Custom CSS to make this `<img>` full screen? and without margins or paddings? I dont want this to be a background image. I have tried using CSS:

```
  <style type="text/css">
img.bg {
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    img.bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px; }
}
```

but it looks like this CSS makes it like a background image. I just need the picture to override the Wordpress theme to make it a full image full screen

Answer (score 0):

Use `width:100vw` instead of `width:100%` or increase the container width to `100vw`

Answer (score 0):

important key word can be used to override styles 
try some thing like this

```
img.bg {
min-height: 100% !important;
min-width: 1024px !important;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but i currently have 3 images like i mention using <img> tag, so i need the first image to appear up, second below the first, and third below the second. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below CSS.

```
img.bg {
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

body{
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but i currently have 3 images like i mention using <img> tag, so i need the first image to appear up, second below the first, and third below the second. how can i do that?

Comment: check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/daq37/   let me know it's working for you or not.

Comment: I know just for image .

Comment: in this fiddle add above CSS.then it's working perfectly.

Comment: seems to work but i dont want spaces between the three images, it needs to be continuous and i have changed float: left to float: botton as i need the images to scroll from top to bottom

Comment: Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/05fu6dsg/1/    hope,it's working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203731/discussion-between-foram-trada-and-rajveer-singh).

Comment: Please check the chat

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your css like this:

```css
img.bg {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.imgworlds.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/generic.jpg" class="bg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want three images below each other where each image is full-screen you can use the following solution.

The .images will lie as a floating layer over your page, just make sure content is above this layer and does not interfere, not the prettiest setup but it shows it can work.

HTML

```
<div class="images">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Photo" class="bg" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Photo" class="bg" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Photo" class="bg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.images {
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.bg {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100vw;
  width: 100%;
}
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdckxr6e/1/)